# Formatting cells to 000-000-0000-0000 in MS Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, regex, text-formatting

I would like to format cells in excel to the following format: 000-000-0000-0000. This is only an example and the zeros can be replaced with other numbers, but the hyphens need to stay.

I think regex might be my friend here, but I've had a lot of trouble with VBA scripts and using them in the past so I was wondering if there's any other way to achieve this?

I/O examples:
123-12-1-255 to 123-012-0001-0255
983-6-9908-12 --> 983-006-9908-0012

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! Qhy do you want to use VBA or Regex? What will be the output if for example you enter 145? Give some examples of inputs and outputs.

Comment: Thanks. I'd rather avoid using VBA or Regex, but those were the options that first came to mind. I've edited the post to include I/O examples because comment formatting doesn't work well for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally have the answer

```
=CONCATENATE("153-";TEXT(LEFT(C2;FIND("-";C2)-1);"000"); "-"; TEXT(MID(C2;FIND("-";C2)+1;FIND("-";C2;FIND("-";C2)+1)-FIND("-";C2)-1);"0000"); "-"; TEXT(RIGHT(C2;LENGTH(C2)-FIND("-";C2;FIND("-";C2)+1));"0000"))
```

Where C2 is the cell I have the original values in. For most English speaking users, you will need to replace the semicolons with commas.

Answer (score 1):

Right Click the cells you need to format- **Format Cells**- **Custom**- enter the format:

```
000-000-0000-0000
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reponse, however this does not work in my case. See the In-out examples I've provided in the edited post.

Answer (score 1):

The difficulty is that with the number strings you have, you actually have text. There is NO custom NUMBER formatting that will work on text to change its parts. (You can do things like have "not a number" displayed wherever text exists, but that is not taking the text itself and operating on it to transform it.)

Nothing in Excel itself can transform the text for you either... not in this manner. You can absolutely easily use string functions to achieve it, but the result will be in a different cell, not the original cell and my impression is you do not want that at all.

If you are importing the data you can import it to some other place in the spreadsheet and place the formulas where the data currently belongs. (If the data source is a file, you can even leave it there.) But if someone is entering it and you need to let them enter it in the body of data, not elsewhere, that won't do. If you can use this, you can either use string functions to create a "hard" version of the result, one containing the dashes in the actual cell content, or, if it would be desirable, the bare numerals, *padded with introduced 0's where needed*, and use custom number formatting to format it. If the source data is not being kept, you would need a step converting the formulas into their data results. Hand done, VBA via a "Click Me" button... but something.

Fortunately, string manipulation in VBA is completely robust, nothing needed is missing, and it's straightforward, no unexpected events need be much worried about. It will let you populate the cell in the end with the desired result, so the properly formed string exists in the original cell. As with a formula approach, you can create bare numeral strings, padded as necessary, and place those in the target cells.

The VBA coding-only approaches would make you do the figuring for padding and such and allow for possibilities in the code. The VBA plus RegEx approach has the niceness that the padding might be pretty easy to arrange, easier than the extra lines of string manipulation code, but there are so few real RegEx gurus around... it seems the odds are you might have a much harder time with the intricacies than with just writing 10-20 extra lines of code.

Or not. Maybe the RegEx side is much more obvious than it looks to me. (I am assuredly NOT one of those RegEx gurus.)

In any case, using strings and string functions or code/RegEx produces a direct, finished result as a string complete with dashes. Producing a set of numerals means a step at the end creating the custom number format. Of course, that is easy, and is already shown, on purpose in `Lee`'s answer and coincidentally in your question itself.

One thing to remember when crafting such a string when some numbers might not fit the really desired model (note `Lee`'s example with two extra digits) is that Excel fits these formats onto the numeral strings from the right, then leftwards. Hence the "12" at the start of that number being tacked onto the leading three digit piece of the output for five digits there and the rest just fine rather than the final four digits becoming six digits. This is more of a problem with some of the more esoteric things people try to accomplish.

Naturally, if you would like to use Power Query, it can take care of this with no great effort, but you wouldn't accomplish it with just the mouse. You would have to write a transformation step or two... Once you learn it though...